# Is there a way to make my text based game work through a notepad/txt.file?

Tags: python

Pretty brand new to programming, so sorry if this isn't the way you guys like things done. I spent a good chunk of this afternoon working on this little game and I was just wondering if there was a way to make it pop up and work through a notepad/text editor/text file? I'm currently just running it through my pycharm, but was wondering if there was anyway I could send it or set it up so I can easily send it to friends?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Pyinstaller allows you to create a standalone executable from python code [Check it out here](https://www.pyinstaller.org/). You can then share that executable file with your friends with Windows machines without requiring them to have Python installed. If your friends run Linux, then you can just share the Python file, since most Linux flavors include Python.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]